# Vagrant/Virtual box error

Tags: virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to run 'vagrant up' on my RHEL VM and i get the following error.
It looks like virtualization is not enabled.Any workaround for this ?

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

```
Command: ["startvm", "d7f1a56f-43bc-4cde-a3de-63bf5414ddd0", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running host machine itself in virtual environment, make sure to expose virtualization flags. Check out the [article](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_enable_nested_virtualization_in_KVM) for KVM and [article](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-2A98801C-68E8-47AF-99ED-00C63E4857F6.html) for VMWare.